# "SSL handshake failure" Oracle ADF Mobile Webservice Integration

Tags: oracle, web-services, mobile, ssl, oracle-adf-mobile

I am new to the Oracle ADF Mobile Application Development. I am trying to access the web service in my application.The web service is perfect as I had use it in my another Core Android application.

But when trying to use the same web service in Oracle ADF Mobile it gives me the following error:

SSL handshake failure

Here, I had also attached the screenshot of the emulator.[image]

I don't get what is the issue.

Please help.Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/security.htm#autoId18

Its from the documentation

Frank